# dartanalyzer reports errors on the getting started tutorial

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

Running dartanalyzer on this snipped found on [flutter.io/get-started/codelab](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/#step-1-create-the-starting-flutter-app) yields these errors:

```
$ dartanalyzer lib/main.dart
Analyzing lib/main.dart...
  error • The function 'MyApp' isn't defined at lib/main.dart:3:23 • undefined_function
  error • 'MaterialApp' isn't a function at lib/main.dart:8:12 • invocation_of_non_function
  error • 'Scaffold' isn't a function at lib/main.dart:10:13 • invocation_of_non_function
  error • 'AppBar' isn't a function at lib/main.dart:11:17 • invocation_of_non_function
  error • 'Text' isn't a function at lib/main.dart:12:18 • invocation_of_non_function
  error • 'Center' isn't a function at lib/main.dart:14:15 • invocation_of_non_function
  error • 'Text' isn't a function at lib/main.dart:15:18 • invocation_of_non_function
7 errors found.

$ dartanalyzer --version
dartanalyzer version 1.24.3
```

What can I do to make the analyzer run correct?

Answer (score 4):

For Flutter projects instead of running `dartanalyzer` you should run `flutter analyze`. Flutter ships with it's own SDK, so the regular dart analyzer doesn't work without some extra configuration - which that command provides.